# java rmi : access control exception, access denied

Tags: java, eclipse, rmi, javac

I'm going through the tutorial at sun's website, try to use RMI.

But when I try to start the server I get this error:

```
ComputeEngine exception:
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1051)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:574)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:340)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at engine.ComputeEngine.main(ComputeEngine.java:31)
```

*Can someone advice on how to remedy this? How do I get rid of this exception, how do i fix it?*

This is where i get the exception (where i drew the arrow on the right of the line):

```
package engine;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import compute.Compute;
import compute.Task;

public class ComputeEngine implements Compute {

    public ComputeEngine() {
        super();
    }

    public <T> T executeTask(Task<T> t) {
        return t.execute();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        }
        try {
            String name = "Compute";
            Compute engine = new ComputeEngine();
            Compute stub =
                (Compute) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(engine, 0);
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            registry.rebind(name, stub); <<<<<------
            System.out.println("ComputeEngine bound");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("ComputeEngine exception:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and finally this is how i start my program:

[image: Arguments to program and jvm]

I'll leave further pertinent information that may be of use underneath:

This is the file ~/.server_policy:

```
grant codeBase "file:/home/jenia/Documents/eclipse/workspace/asti01/bin" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

This is the tree of the project directory:

```
/home/jenia/Documents/eclipse/workspace/asti01$ tree
.
├── bin
│   ├── client
│   │   ├── ComputePi.class
│   │   └── Pi.class
│   ├── compute
│   │   ├── Compute.class
│   │   └── Task.class
│   └── engine
│       └── ComputeEngine.class
└── src
    ├── client
    │   ├── ComputePi.java
    │   └── Pi.java
    ├── compute
    │   ├── Compute.java
    │   └── Task.java
    ├── compute.jar
    └── engine
        └── ComputeEngine.java
```

this is the tree of the folder ~/public_html

```
/home/jenia/public_html/
└── classes
    ├── client
    │   └── Pi.class
    └── compute.jar
```

Comment: EOFException in RMI usually results from a SecurityManager problem at the other end. Can you try it without the codebase and security managers?

Comment: i dont get what you mean

Comment: If you don't understand 'without the codebase and security managers' I can't help you further with your old question. Your new question is completely different: see below.

Comment: all right, I fixed the question. what do you think is the problem? why do i get the exception?

Comment: ***'Fixed'?*** You've changed it completely. It started out as an EOFException; then it became a ConnectException; now it's an AccessControlException. No doubt when you get past that you'll change it again. This is mad.

Answer (score 1):

1. The answer to your original question is that EOFException in RMI usually results from a SecurityManager problem at the other end. Try it without the codebase and security managers.
2. The answer to the 2nd version of your question is that the Registry isn't running, and getRegistry() doesn't start it. createRegistry() does.
3. The answer to the third version of your question is the same as to the first version.
4. When you get past all this to the next error, which will undoubtedly be `ClassNotFoundException` when binding, the solution is to run the Registry with the correct classpath.
5. When you get past *that* to the next error, which will undoubtedly be `ClassNotFoundException` when looking-up, the solution is to run the *client* with the correct classpath.

Comment: For clarity and for the assistance of future readers, that was the answer to your second question. You are now up to at least your third. Curiously enough, my original comment about removing the security managers and codebase still applies.

Answer (score 1):

To reiterate @EJP's original comment:

Ignore everything in the tutorial related to configuring/using a SecurityManager.  Don't attempt to use remote code loading.  These "features" greatly increase the complexity of using rmi and 99% of users *don't actually need them*.

Comment: I agree completely. Sadly I said exactly the same thing hours ago with no effect.

Comment: @EJP - ha, saw your answer but didn't read back through all the comments on the OP.  updated.

Answer (score 0):

If your RMI Registry Server is running in Localhost then you should use `127.0.0.1` not `127.0.1.1`

Pass in `127.0.0.1` when starting `ComputePi`

Comment: sorry i dont understand. pass it where? when i execute the command in the shell? if so, how?

Comment: You don't know how you're running your own programs?

Comment: no i do. i did not know how to pass in the argument to the program and to the java virtual machine. but now im using eclipse and there are text fields for this. But I still get the same error (on the ip 127.0.0.1)

Comment: Another error *such as what?* This question is getting thoroughly ridiculous.